# There is No Parameter $3 SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, transactions

I've made this function in postgres that should insert a FlightBooking tuple only if that row is associated with a LeadCustomer and is doesn't already exist; if it does, just update the num_seats and total_cost.

The problem is that I'm receiving an error saying that the 3$ parameter doesn't exist  (i.e. "there is no parameter $3"), why is this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_FlightBooking(INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER, CHAR(1), TIMESTAMP, DECIMAL)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM LeadCustomer WHERE CustomerID = $2) THEN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM FlightBooking WHERE CustomerID = $2) THEN

      INSERT INTO LeadCustomer VAlUES($2, 'Tom', 'Mann', '08, Lilac Street, Oxford', 'tomisawesome@gmail.com');
      INSERT INTO FlightBooking VAlUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);

      ALTER TABLE flightbooking ADD CONSTRAINT chk_flightbooking_availability
      CHECK (check_Seats($3) >= 0);
      ALTER TABLE FlightBooking DROP CONSTRAINT chk_flightbooking_availability;

    ELSE

      UPDATE FlightBooking
      SET NumSeats  = NumSeats + $4, TotalCost = TotalCost - $7
      WHERE CustomerID = $2;

      ALTER TABLE flightbooking ADD CONSTRAINT chk_flightbooking_availability
      CHECK (check_Seats($3) >= 0);
      ALTER TABLE FlightBooking DROP CONSTRAINT chk_flightbooking_availability;

    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is a example using the function giving this error:

```
SELECT * FROM update_FlightBooking(10006, 20006, 30004, 4, 'r', '01/02/2021 22:55:44', 799.96);
```

Comment: Should the function input value for the TIMESTAMP be cast or converted from quoted text to a TIMESTAMP data type value?

Comment: Hasn't been problematic so far as i'm aware, I don't think I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I'm not sure what the postgresql casting function is. I'm asking: if postgresql automagically casts `'01/02/2021 22:55:44'` to TIMESTAMP type.  Some SQL might have syntax casting syntax like `CONVERT('01/02/2021 22:55:44', 'TIMESTAMP')`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is linked to the check constraints using $3:

```
ALTER TABLE flightbooking ADD CONSTRAINT chk_flightbooking_availability
      CHECK (check_Seats($3) >= 0);
```

There are some restrictions on a function used in a check constraint but I have not found them in documentation.

I can reproduce something similar with:

```
create or replace function update_t(integer)
returns void
as $$
begin
alter table t add constraint cc check(check_f($1));
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

select update_t(1);
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "alter table t add constraint cc check(check_f($1))"
PL/pgSQL function update_t(integer) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Comment: It can't find parameter one now lol. I think it's referring to the parameter for the update_t function but no idea why it's making the error :( might be that check() doesn't support functions?

Comment: CHECK(check_Seats(30004) >= 0) works but obviously don't want to hard code the value in